# Unable to subclass UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've created a UITableViewCell subclass as below. All I've done is added a label to the cell's content view and set its text.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
}
@end

#import "CustomTableViewCell.h" 
@implementation CustomTableViewCell

@synthesize horizontalTableView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
    {

        UIView *myContentView = self.contentView;

        UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30)];
        l.text = @"Hi";

        [myContentView addSubview:l];

        [l release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now I use this custom cell in my table view this way:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 300) reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
     return cell;
}
```

However the labels do not show in my table view. What am I missing ?

Comment: use NSlog statements inside and check if control goes to the `init` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:`is deprecated, the designated initializer for `UITableViewCell` is `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`. Probably when you are using the current method, `contentView` is not created, so you are adding your label to `nil`.

What's more, you aren't even calling your overridden method - you have overridden plain old `initWithFrame:`.

Comment: Everything is wired up and the cellForRowAtIndexPath is called. Its just that the custom cell with label is not shown !!

Comment: This answer is correct. You need to implement `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` instead of `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier`.